# Understanding The Threading and Queue combination in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, queue, python-multithreading

I started looking into create threads in Python. I did some theory search first to understand how Threads work in Python. I also went ahead to read about the use of Queue in Python and how it can help solving trivial Threading problems. I was able to understand separate codes for each. Then I came across the following tutorial :

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-threadingpython/

It shows the relevance of Thread and Queue in Python and how it can speed up the execution process under certain circumstances.

I am having difficulty in understanding some areas of the code

```
def main():

        #spawn a pool of threads, and pass them queue instance 
        for i in range(5):
          t = ThreadUrl(queue)
          t.setDaemon(True)
          t.start()

       #populate queue with data   
          for host in hosts:
            queue.put(host)

       #wait on the queue until everything has been processed     
       queue.join()

      main()
      print "Elapsed Time: %s" % (time.time() - start)
```

In the first for loop the multiple threads are created and a queue instance is passed to it. But from my understanding the queue is empty as of now.

In the next for loop

`for host in hosts`:

The host values are pushed into the queue. Now how is this Queue data assigned to threads?

Lastly, what is the use of `queue.join()` with relevance to this program?

Answer (score 1):

"In the first for loop the multiple threads are created and a queue instance is passed to it. But from my understanding the queue is empty as of now."

Yes, the threads are started but they have no work to do yet.

`for host in hosts:`

"The host values are pushed into the queue. Now how is this Queue data assigned to threads?"

by the Queue instance

"what is the use of `queue.join()` with relevance to this program?"

`join` causes your program to wait until the threads have all finished processing and their outputs are collected by the queue instance. Your program will block at this point until the queue has completed.